# Inserting element into a div lost word-wrap properties

Tags: jquery, html, css, word-wrap, removing-whitespace

I have a problem trying to dynamically modify a DIV element's content.
The DIV contain a series of elements, and I want clone the last one changing some information.

```js
function add_ele_wrong(id){
  var id_c = 'c'+id;
  var id_n = 'c'+(id+1);
  $('#'+id_c+'f1').parent().after( $('#'+id_c+'f1').parent().clone()[0].outerHTML.replace(RegExp(id_c, 'g'),id_n) );
}

function add_ele(id){
  var id_c = 'c'+id;
  var id_n = 'c'+(id+1);
  $('#'+id_c+'f1').parent().after( '&nbsp'+$('#'+id_c+'f1').parent().clone()[0].outerHTML.replace(RegExp(id_c, 'g'),id_n) );
}
```

```css
#container {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid black;
  word-wrap: break-word;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id=container >
  <span id=c1 class=chapter style="white-space:nowrap;" >
    <span id="c1f1" onClick="add_ele(1);">These work 1</span>
    &nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <span id="c1f2" onClick="add_ele_wrong(1);">These don't work 2</span>
  </span>
  <span id=c2 class=chapter style="white-space:nowrap;" >
    <span id="c2f1" onClick="add_ele(2);">These work 3</span>
    &nbsp;-&nbsp;
    <span id="c2f2" onClick="add_ele_wrong(2);">These don't work 4</span>
  </span>
</div>
```

The "original" chapter spans stay well inside the div following the width limit, but when I add a new one 'c3' it stay "connected" with the c2 not wrapping (and going out to the div) and is the same for a 'c4' and so on.

I'm using some wrong CSS or JQ instruction?

Thanks for suggestions.

EDIT. Thanks to [misorude](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10283047/misorude) I solved the problem, and following his suggestion I chenged the question inserting a sniped with the right and the wrong solution.

EDIT 2. I found that if you don't want to insert a space between elements, you have to set CSS display properies of the elements to inline-block and word-wrap works anyway.

Comment: could you please update your question by adding your css as well?

Comment: This is likely a whitespace issue. Between your `#c1` and `#c2` elements, there is a text node containing whitespace, so the browser can break the content there if necessary. By appending your cloned element _directly_ behind `#c2` however, you are leaving out this whitespace - this is as if you had written `...</span><span ...` directly in your initial HTML to begin with.